# How to runs macros on multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have several macros so I use call macro to run them simultaneously but it only works on `worksheet1` so now I want the macros to run on all worksheets in a workbook. Is there a way whereby i use `callmacros` to run the first macro for `worksheet1` and then the other macros to run on all worksheets.

```
Sub callmacros()
    Call macro1 '(run on only worksheet1)
    Call macro2 '(run on all worksheets)
    Call macro3 '(run on all worksheets)
End Sub
```

Pls help. Thanks

Comment: Show us what do you have in Macro1,2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

**In Sheet1**

```
Sub Test1()
    MsgBox "1"
End Sub
```

**In Sheet2**

```
Sub Test2()
    MsgBox "3"
End Sub
```

**In Sheet3**

```
Sub Test3()
    MsgBox "3"
End Sub
```

**In ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Sheets(1).Test1
    Call Sheets(2).Test2
    Call Sheets(3).Test3
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would your macro script run my macros for the worksheets?